# Open a file on Windows with Python 3.5

Tags: windows, python-3.x

Just installed Python 3.5 on Windows.  Trying to open a file, per the documentation, I'm supposed to use `fopen` for file reads.

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

f = open(C:\Users\median\Desktop\ics\2014_work_order_detail4.txt)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f = open(C:\Users\median\Desktop\ics\2014_work_order_detail4.txt)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

 f = open(C:\Users\median\Desktop\ics\2014_work_order_detail4.txt);
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f = open(C:\Users\median\Desktop\ics\2014_work_order_detail4.txt);
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

 f = open("C:\Users\median\Desktop\ics\2014_work_order_detail4.txt");
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

How do I open this file?  Documentation does not seem to address these issues on Windows.

Is it a pathing problem?

Comment: Try escaping the slashes to double-slashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\median\Desktop\ics\2014_work_order_detail4.txt");
```

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Why doesn't the documentation say that?  https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Backslashes have a specific meaning in string literals. That's why you have to escape all backslashes in order to get the desidered path.

Comment: "Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters." Take a look at: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html